# Issue failing to get multiple results in CK query where the same record may be returned more than once

Tags: swift, cloudkit

I've got a table in CloudKit (UserCourse) which holds a reference to a user, a reference to a course and a variety of summary data for that User+Course combo (e.g., date starte, status, etc).  A user could choose to take the same course multiple times.

In one view of my app, I show the count of courses a user has taken - this query works fine and shows the total count, including duplicate versions of a user+course combination.

I then have a subsequent view, where I want to list out all of the courses the logged in user has taken, with course details.  My issue is that I'm only able to get a single copy of the Course that has been duplicated.

First I have a query that gets all records from the UserCourses table for that user.  From the results, I get the references to all of the courses and pass that as an input to a subsequent query that attempts to get all the courses from CK so that I can display the view to the user of all the courses they have taken.

The issue is that I'm unable to get two copies of the same course (say one in progress and one completed, as an example).  I've tried querying by recordName, but I understand that isn't possible.  However, when I try to convert from recordName to Record ID (below) - I get different record IDs for the same record name and my query only returns one instance of the Course, not two.

```
    recordIDs.append(CKRecord.ID(recordName: recordName))
```

and the relevant code below.  Open to suggestions on how to address it.  I'm guessing I'm going about it the wrong way and should be designing my queries differently!

```
 func getCoursesByReference(for references: [CKRecord.Reference],
                              _ completion: @escaping ([Course]?,Error?) -> Void) {
    var recordIDs: [CKRecord.ID] = []

    for each in references { //loop through the references being passed in
 // and because you can't query by recordName in cloudkit, then convert to record ID

        var recordName = each.recordID.recordName
        recordIDs.append(CKRecord.ID(recordName: recordName))
    }

    //my predicate now has two different record IDs for the same recordName and as such my results set is 1 item instead of two

    var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "recordID IN %@", recordIDs)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Course", predicate: predicate)

    ....remainder of code
```

Comment: the IN predicate only matches cases which occur IN the set which your providing, not the number of times it occurs in the set. The only way to get repetitions is to do a separate search for each recordID against the courses table.

Comment: ahhhhhhh.  I'd assumed the issue was that because I was creating an array of record IDs that the issue was the IDs didn't match and that is why I only got one result back.  Not that I was being a bit dumb and missing the obvious.  Thanks @johnelemans that's a big help!